# Convert Lead to Contact with trigger on Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the following code on the trigger, but when it runs I get an error message on salesforce page.

(You encountered some errors when trying to save this record
There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help.)

```
trigger OppLeadtoClient on Opportunity (After update) {
    If(trigger.new[0].StageName=='Closed Won'){

Lead ld = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE accountid__c =: trigger.new[0].Accountid ];
       Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
       lc.setLeadId(ld.Id);
            //lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
            LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);   
            Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
            System.debug('converted');

}}
```

Comment: Are you using your administrator user with full permissions? If not, check if your user has the permission to create accounts, contacts and opportunities.

Comment: When you select the lead in your query based on account id, what is the status of that lead?

Comment: Im using a Developer Edition, as System Administrator, and the Lead Status is "New". And the trigger also throws the error when i try to register a new Contact from scartch, i mean creating the Contact-> adding the field values -> inserting the Contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem, the Lead was assigned to a queue as owner, and when i tried to edit it from a trigger, it seems not to have the rights even if im doing it from a System Admin Role.